# Изменение каждой записи ячейки

Tags: sql, python, postgresql, python-3.x

Есть таблица, в ней есть параметры, которые время от времени следует обновлять.

Поэтому вопрос: как из таблицы вытащить параметры по одному?

Пример кода который должен вытаскивать записи:

```
SELECT trader_capital, stock_id, name 
FROM trader 
WHERE stock_id=11 and trader_capital="Что сюда?" AND name='Как задать переменную?';
```

Answer (score 1):

Для изменения в таблице используйте update, а если у вас есть stock_id(у вас написано = 11), то вам не нужно изменять по одному, да и прописывать все параметры не нужно, id волне достаточно для поиска нужной записи.